# login/logout, config, session inactivity codes in php

Tags: php, forms, authentication

I have a php file **admin_trace.php** in which I have integrated everything (config, session inactivity, login/logout, username/password verification and JS codes).

The php file admin_trace.php belongs to the following url http://example.com/admin_trace.php (let us suppose)

In the php file **admin_trace.php**, I have

**a.** **database configuration code**

**b.** **session inactivity code** (which forces logout of the page when there is no activity)

**c.** **login/logout code**

**d.** **username/password verification code**

**e.** **if user is not logged in then it it will display the login page**.

```
// Is user logged in?
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION['pageadmin'])){ ?>
    <form action="/admin_trace.php" method="post">
        <div style='width:350px;'>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Login</legend>
                <div>
                    <label for="user_name">User Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="user_name">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="user_pass">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="user_pass">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button type="submit">Login</button>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </form>
    <?PHP } else { ?>
```

**f.**  **JS code at the bottom**

The issue which I am having right now that all my codes are in one file **admin_trace.php** which is making things difficult and making some part of the code **(like JS)** not working

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what would be the best way to architect any login form page that has **config code**, **session inactivity code**, **login/logout code**, **username/password verification code** and **JS code**. When I say architect I meant to say the relative locations of the files w.r.t. to **admin_trace.php** where **config code**, **session inactivity code**, **login/logout code**, **username/password code** etc will be placed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP has the ability to split code into multiple files. You can bring this code in conditionally with `if` statements via the [`include`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) and [`require`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) statements (and corresponding `include_once` and `require_once`.

Comment: Hi Chris, in the `admin_trace.php` file, I have included `include 'Config/config.php';`.  Do you think it would be a good idea to include `session inactivity`, `login/logout` codes in a different file ?

Comment: There is no right or wrong in this regard, but generally if you can isolate code that does one specific thing to a file, and that has little or no dependencies elsewhere, you will find it easier to reason about your code in the future. If your session activity redirects people on inactivity (or in any other way ends the process) then that makes sense to isolate. If your login/logout is mostly HTML/JS, that too makes sense. There isn't anything technically invalid with putting things into a giant file, either, as long as it works for you (and whoever has to maintain it in the future).

Comment: Hi, I hope all is well.  I have one more [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63691611/how-to-make-a-button-execute-a-php-script). It's not similar. I am wondering if you can have a look.